# Prove that if $A$ is transitive, then $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is transitive too.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My book on set theory says

> Prove that is a set $A$ is transitive, then $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is also transitive, where $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the power set of $A$.

I don't know understand how. Let $A=\{a,b\}$. Clearly it is transitive. Now $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\emptyset\}$. This is clearly not transitive.

Comment: What do you mean by a set to be transitive?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane- Transitive set: Say $A$ is a set, and $x\in A$. If $y\in x$, then $y\in A$. Example: $A=\{\{a,b\},a,b\}$. As $a$ and $b$ belong to $\{a,b\}\in A$, they also have to belong to $A$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane- [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set) may be of help.

Comment: $A=\{a,b\}$ is hardly ever transitive. For example, if $a=\emptyset$ and $b=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, then the set $A=\{a,b\}$ is not transitive, because $b$ is an element of $A$ but $b$ is not a subset of $A$.

Comment: @bof- Thanks for bringing up a point that has always confused me. Why should we ever equate $a$ and $b$ with other sets, treating them like variables? Why can't they be individual elements bearing no resemblance to any other set whatsoever? $A=\{a,b\}$ is transitive because no element of $A$ contains an element which is not in $A$.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking, read my answer. You are asking that $a,b$ be urelements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your book forbids [urelements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement). Equivalent definition of transitive: $x\in A\implies x\subset A$. Your set $A=\{a,b\}$ isn't transitive in general.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. I had come across this equivalent statement, but hadn't given it much though. I suppose only non-empty sets can be elements of a transitive set.

Comment: And the empty set. $\{\emptyset\}$ is transitive.

Answer (score 6):

A set $A$ is transitive iff $a\in A$ implies $a\subseteq A$.

Let $A$ be transitive and let $B\in\mathcal P\left(A\right)$ - or equivalently $B\subseteq A$.

Then for $a\in B$ we find $a\in A$, so
$a\subseteq A$ - or equivalently $a\in\mathcal P\left(A\right)$ - because $A$
is transitive.

This for evey $a\in B$ so $B\subseteq\mathcal P\left(A\right)$.

Proved is now that $\mathcal P\left(A\right)$ is transitive.

Comment: I've been looking for a proof that $V_{\alpha}$ is transitive where $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal. This is it! Thanks. With regards,

Answer (score 0):

Your example is transitive isn't it?

Comment: How? We have $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\emptyset\}$. Now $\{a\}\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $a\in \{a\}$. However, $a\notin \mathcal{P}(A)$

Comment: By definition of power sets if a and b belong {a,b} then they must belong to the power set see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Comment: Yes. But $a\neq \{a\}$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are getting at. But if a and b are not sets, then the power set is {}, because it is the set of subsets of {a,b} and a and b are not sets and therefore not subsets

Comment: Actually the power set is {{a,b}, ∅} of course